How to solve issue with brainconn issue
I am trying to run the following code:
#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_github("sidchop/brainconn")

library(brainconn)
x <- example_unweighted_undirected
brainconn(atlas ="schaefer300_n7", conmat=x, node.size = 3, view="ortho")

that I called by unpackaging all the functions from this website page
https://github.com/sidchop/brainconn/tree/master
Unfortunately I am getting this code
 Error in `handlers[[1L]]()`:
    ! No layout function defined for objects of class <matrix>
    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

That I tried to correct
library(brainconn)
    x <- example_unweighted_undirected
    brainconn(atlas ="schaefer300_n7", conmat= as.matrix(x), node.size = 3, view="ortho")

that returns the same error. Do you know how to possibly solve this? Just to add some detail, I am copying here below the errormessage in rlang
! No layout function defined for objects of class <matrix>
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Error in `handlers[[1L]]()`:
! No layout function defined for objects of class <matrix>
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─global brainconn(...)
  2. │ └─global build_plot(...)
  3. │   ├─ggraph::create_layout(graph = conmat, layout = "stress", circular = TRUE)
  4. │   └─ggraph:::create_layout.default(...)
  5. │     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
  6. │     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
  7. │     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  8. │     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
  9. │     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 10. │     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 11. │     ├─tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(graph)
 12. │     └─tidygraph:::as_tbl_graph.matrix(graph)
 13. │       └─tidygraph:::guess_matrix_type(x)
 14. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 15.   └─rlang (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
 16.     └─handlers[[1L]](cnd)
Run rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE) to see 2 hidden frames.

    > rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)
    <error/rlang_error>
    Error in `handlers[[1L]]()`:
    ! No layout function defined for objects of class <matrix>
    ---
    Backtrace:
         ▆
      1. ├─global brainconn(...)
      2. │ └─global build_plot(...)
      3. │   ├─ggraph::create_layout(graph = conmat, layout = "stress", circular = TRUE)
      4. │   └─ggraph:::create_layout.default(...)
      5. │     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
      6. │     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
      7. │     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
      8. │     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
      9. │     │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
     10. │     │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
     11. │     ├─tidygraph::as_tbl_graph(graph)
     12. │     └─tidygraph:::as_tbl_graph.matrix(graph)
     13. │       └─tidygraph:::guess_matrix_type(x)
     14. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
     15.   └─rlang (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
     16.     └─handlers[[1L]](cnd)
     17.       └─cli::cli_abort("No layout function defined for objects of class {.cls {class(graph)[1]}}")
     18.         └─rlang::abort(...)

and the error I get when I run the instaallation command is:
remotes::install_github("sidchop/brainconn")
Downloading GitHub repo sidchop/brainconn@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/sidchop/brainconn/tarball/HEAD' failed
> remotes::install_github("sidchop/brainconn", dependenciees = T)
Downloading GitHub repo sidchop/brainconn@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/sidchop/brainconn/tarball/HEAD' failed

Thanks

I just ran the above example and have a plotted brain, so can't reproduce. We install (brainconn) the same way, though I generally look at all dependencies and install them first, and still remotes:: helpfully chides me about updating packages, of which there are an enormous number to arrive at 'brainconn'. If you take the bait and Run rlang::last_trace() and put the trace here above, perhaps we can solve.

Could you please tell which version of R are you using? I will share that rlang::last_trace() too

Ok, thanks for you kind reply so far. I have attached the error that you mentioned . Anyway I want just remind that I had to download manually from the repository the .zip file with all the scripts enclosed, to open the library, because additionaly, when I try to run the command to install brainconn, I have attached the error that it returns.

Let's change the install process. Have a look at pak and who's driving it (the developers). Install it, then try pak::pkg_install("sidchop/brainconn"), then example.

It seems to have downloaded everything from the repository, but I cannot see the brainconn packages among the packages I have in R. I tried to run again your code and the output is `pak::pkg_install("sidchop/brainconn")
ℹ No downloads are needed
✔ 1 pkg + 92 deps: kept 42 [3.9s]`. So error is always the same

And now library(brainconn) and run example? You should get 'Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will
replace the existing one.` and the plot.

No..I have run it, but I am getting always the same error. But in any case the package is not fundable in the packages installed

Start over, i.e. remove.packages('brainconn), and presumably pak::pkg_remove('brainconn'), open a new session, and try again with pak, that I suggest as it resolves all your dependencies, which at this point may be none (missing)

I am getting again the same error....but this time at least I have the package downloaded

Using pak or remotes to do the package re-install?  You are on Windows? I can't test problems over there as I'm on Ubuntu. And are you running this from a terminal or RStudio? And, in a new session, sessionInfo() results above, please, after library(brainconn)

I am on Windows, yes and I am runnign code from the Console. Actually I can see that if I enter another matrix (created on my own) at the conmat intup, then I can get the brain plot with the only brainconn() function. On contrary, the brainconn3D accepts the matrix used in my post and plots the brain fine. I cannot understand what is problematic with brainconn() when plots matrix, used as example.

Could ypou please chek how this matrix looks like (length, row, columns, whether there is some 1 or in cells there always 0)?
